# Styling Contact Form 7 checkbox when checked

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox, contact-form-7

I want to change out the visual of the checked checkbox from blue background to match my theme. I cant seem to get it to show and have tried several options for the checked status. Any help for what selector to use on this would be very helpful.

Selectors that didn't work out.

```
.wpcf7-list-item > label:after > input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {}
.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:after {}
span.wpcf7-list-item.first > input[type=checkbox]:checked {}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out through the post from Victory Osiobe that you can use this to affect the contact form 7 checkboxes color when selected.

```
.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  accent-color: green;
}
```

Confirmed working when inserted to Appearance>Additional CSS